# How to copy a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, copy

I have a problem with value assignment when dealing with list of lists:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

arr1 = arr.copy()

arr1[1][0] = 15
```

It turns out that arr is also affected by the last command. How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Use `arr1 = copy.deepcopy(arr)` to copy all the way down.

Comment: It did work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As quamrana mentions, you can use `deepcopy`.

```py
import copy

a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: I did try this method but it did not work, only deepcopy works by far

Answer (score 0):

A long way:

```
    arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    arr1 = []
    for i in arr:
      arr1.append(i)
```

Comment: I think this is the same as `arr.copy()` that the OP uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
arr1=copy.deepcopy(arr)
arr1[1][0]=15
```